# How long redis stores data (key-value)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I have a variable which I need for 8 days. During this period it should be available via $redis.get('my_variable') in RoR application. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is entirely possible. To be specific about when your keys will expire, use the the [`EXPIRE`](http://redis.io/commands/expire) or [`EXPIREAT`](http://redis.io/commands/expireat) commands.

Using `EXPIRE` with the [`redis`](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb) ruby gem would look like this:

```
$redis.set("my_variable", "foo")
$redis.expire("my_variable", 8.days)
$redis.get("my_variable") # => "foo"
sleep(8.days)
$redis.get("my_variable") # => nil
```

`EXPIREAT` works similarly:

```
$redis.expireat("my_variable", 8.days.from_now.to_i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Redis is a key-value storage, that keeps data in RAM, but it can also write it to hard drive.

So it is not problem to keep data for 8 days in redis. Even if you will restart it.

Just configure it properly.